# How to use nth-child() in bootstrap column with article

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use nth-child() to target an `<article>` inside a bootstrap grid but obviously the class selector I am using is incorrect.

Here is the html generated in the browser. There are 6 of these but I posted code for 1 to keep the number of lines down.

```
<div class="ld_course_grid col-sm-8 col-md-4 ">
    <article id="post-60" class="thumbnail course post-60 sfwd-courses type-sfwd-courses status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry ast-article-single">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3 class="entry-title">Title</h3>
            <p class="entry-content">Some lorem text</p>
            <p class="ld_course_grid_button"><a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="#" rel="bookmark">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
<div class="ld_course_grid col-sm-8 col-md-4 ">
    <article id="post-256" class="thumbnail course post-256 sfwd-courses type-sfwd-courses status-publish hentry ast-article-single">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3 class="entry-title">Second Title</h3>
            <p class="entry-content">More lorem text</p>
            <p class="ld_course_grid_button"><a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href="#" rel="bookmark">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

And I tried something like this:

```
.ld_course_grid article:nth-child(2) {
   background-color: red;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Well the code you posted contains only one `article` inside the grid, so looking for a second one will find nothing.

Comment: Indeed it's not clear what element you are trying to select

Comment: Good point. But there are 6 all together. I just posted one to keep lines of code down

Comment: They are all the same except the id is different for each ie: unique id. But the rest of the code is the same

Comment: Well if you're sure there's more than just the one `article` shown, then there's no way that rule isn't taking effect. Beyond that, I'd check the CSS file is loading in general, and then check in the DOM whether the style rule is being overridden by another rule somewhere.

Comment: I have updated the question to show 2 instead of just the 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
.ld_course_grid:nth-child(2) article {
   background-color: red;
}
```

It will target the second div with `.ld_course_grid` class and inside this div, the article.

That's because your HTML structure only contain one article in `.ld_course_grid` element, so `:nth-child(2)` have to apply to this element instead of the `article`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
.ld_course_grid:nth-child(2) .status-publish{
 background-color: red;
 }
```